# Creating a Stack Exchange repository on GitHub

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, github

I have a suggestion. My friend is a member on [UnixHub](http://forums.unixhub.net/), not me. I took a look at it and I noticed that [they have a GitHub](https://github.com/UnixHub) repository.

I thought: why don't we create a user called *StackExchange* on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub)? And then create a repository for each programming site on Stack Exchange. Users will be able to post codes there and embed gists here, if they have GitHub accounts and **if they want to**.

Good codes will become popular on GitHub, and snippets will have better google ranking. Users will definitely be more encouraged to write good code. They can brag about having many users on GitHub. I think it has many advantages, and I can't think of disadvantages.

Comment: We don't really want code held elsewhere. Within the question itself is where it belongs

Comment: Yup. SE is designed as a self-contained resource (like wikipedia) that can be downloaded offline and be used even if the website no longer exists. That's why we have SEDE and the Data Dumps.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I didn't know that prior to asking the the question, yes i knew that you dump the data but didn't knew that SE is designed to be self contained, because you use imgur, so I thought why not github. thanks for letting me know

Comment: Imgur vs Github, you gotta a point. Can you expand the feature-request based on this and SE's self-contained nature?

Answer (score 1):

There wouldn't be a problem, per se, with having all of the code snippets on GitHub as well as on Stack Exchange. The problem would arise because it breaks the `Self-Contained` part of SSCCE. If the page goes down, then the code snippet is lost forever. All relevant code should be in the question itself